# find and copy (multiple) values in column

Tags: excel, vba

- I have a simple table where I want to search column A for a value via `A1:A10`.
- When it finds a value it should copy/paste it to the correspond ending cell in column B. 
  -Moreover it would be nice to search for multiple values like
  *"value1 value2 value3* and to copy all found values in A to B.

[image: my table]

The output should be:

[image]

And for multiple values:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I had to replace the functions with german, but it won't work for me.

[image]

- For B2 I added: `=GLÄTTEN(VERKETTEN(D2;" ";E2;" ";F2;" ";G2))`
- For C2 I added: `=GLÄTTEN(VERKETTEN(B2;" ";D2;" ";E2;" ";F2;" ";G2))`
- For C10 I added: `=GLÄTTEN(LINKS(B10;FINDEN(" ";B10)))`
- For D10 I added: `=GLÄTTEN(LINKS(B11;FINDEN(" ";B11)))`
- For E10 I added: `=GLÄTTEN(LINKS(B12;FINDEN(" ";B12)))`
- For F10 I added: `=GLÄTTEN(B13)`
- For B11 I added: `=TEIL(B10;LÄNGE(C10)+2;99)`
- For B12 I added: `=TEIL(B11;LÄNGE(D10)+2;99)`
- For B13 I added: `=TEIL(B12;LÄNGE(E10)+2;99)`

The translation I got from [here](http://www.piuha.fi/excel-function-name-translation/?page=deutsch-english.html).

Comment: Sorry I didn't follow. Can you also show desired output?

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited my question.

Comment: This should be possible using VBA, do you mind?

Comment: Could you give me a hint for this? I am not familiar with VBA excel.

Comment: Did you consider RegEx add in for Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it efficiently in VBA as below

- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> to open the Visual Basic Editor (VBE).
- From the menu, choose *Insert-Module.*
- copy and paste the code into the code window at right.
- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> to return to Excel
- run the macro from the Developer tab for *Excel 2007* and higher, for *Excel 2003* use `...Tools-Macro-Macros`

[image]

```
enter code here
Sub QuickFInd()
Dim X As Variant
Dim Y As Variant
Dim vWords As Variant
Dim Vword As Variant
Dim lngCnt As Long

X = Range("A2:A8").Value2
ReDim Y(1 To UBound(X), 1 To 1)
vWords = Split([b10].Value)

For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X)
    For Each Vword In vWords
        If InStr(X(lngCnt, 1), Vword) > 0 Then Y(lngCnt, 1) = Y(lngCnt, 1) & Vword & Chr(32)
    Next Vword
Next

[b2].Resize(UBound(Y), 1).Value2 = Y

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, what does the last line "[b2].resize(Ubound"... do?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved your problem with VBA code. To use it, create a VBA module in the excel workbook and paste the following code in. Then go back to the worksheet you want it to run on, and click "Macros" and select "Search".

Let me know how it works ~
**Example:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
Public Sub search()
    'Enter the location of your "Key Word" cell here (where you want the search values to come from)
    Dim KeyCell As String: KeyCell = "B11"

    'Enter the range you would like to search here
    Dim searchRange As Range: Set searchRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2", "A11")

    'Enter the column you want to print to
    Dim printColumn As String: printColumn = "B"

    '##### the real program starts here ####
    'create an array of values that we will search for
    Dim values() As String
    'each item in the values array is separated by a space in the "Key Word" cell
    values = Split(CStr(ActiveSheet.Range(KeyCell).Value), " ")

    Dim dataCell As Object
    'now we loop through each cell in the search range
    For Each dataCell In searchRange
        'loop through each value in our array of values
        For Each v In values
            'check to see if our value is in the cell we are searching
            If InStr(1, CStr(dataCell.Value), CStr(v), vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
                'print
                With ActiveSheet.Range(printColumn & dataCell.Row)
                    .Value = .Value & " " & CStr(v)
                End With
            End If
        Next v
    Next dataCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only a search without PASTE or VBA, you can follow the scheme:

[image]

and add formula:

```
B2 -> =TRIM(CONCATENATE(D2;" ";E2;" ";F2;" ";G2))
C2 -> =IF(IFERROR(FIND(C$10;$A2)>0;"")=TRUE;C$10;"")    and autocomplete

C10 -> =TRIM(LEFT(B10;IFERROR(FIND(" ";B10);99)))       CORRECT !
D10 -> =TRIM(LEFT(B11;IFERROR(FIND(" ";B11);99)))       CORRECT !
E10 -> =TRIM(LEFT(B12;IFERROR(FIND(" ";B12);99)))       CORRECT !
F10 -> =TRIM(B13)

B11 -> =MID(B10;LEN(C10)+2;99)
B12 -> =MID(B11;LEN(D10)+2;99)
B13 -> =MID(B12;LEN(E10)+2;99)
```

Hiding the Support Formula Columns. You can add how many words you want... obviusly adding other formulas.
If you need to add phisically the values, you can add a column between A & B and copy and paste with value the moved column "C" (Ex B). Modify the C2 formula in:

```
=TRIM(CONCATENATE(B2;" ";D2;" ";E2;" ";F2;" ";G2))           and autocomplete...
```

This formulas add the keys already saved... (No duplicate check).
I have correct the formula... Previously work only with 4 key...

Comment: Big thanks for your help! Unfortunately this does not work for me. See my edited question. I hope you can give me further instructions on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
=IF(IFERROR(FIND($B$10,A2,1),0)>0,$B$10&" ","")&IF(IFERROR(FIND($B$11,A2,1),0)>0,$B$11&" ","")&IF(IFERROR(FIND($B$12,A2,1),0)>0,$B$12&" ","")
```

[image: Example]

And just auto-fill that down for all your text items.